# Docker centos7 image: psutil get installed on Windows/Linux but failed on Mac

Tags: python, docker, centos7, psutil

This Dockerfile works fine on Windows/Linux

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN yum -y install python3 gcc
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install psutil
```

I build the image by doing

```
docker build -t anytag .
```

[image]

but **the same Dockerfile** fails on MacOS. I tried in two different Macs (M1 chip)

The error I get is

```
#0 93.73   gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=591 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/psutil/_psutil_common.o
#0 93.73   psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#0 93.73    #include <Python.h>
#0 93.73                       ^
#0 93.73   compilation terminated.
#0 93.73   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
#0 93.73   ----------------------------------------
#0 93.73   ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
#0 93.73   Building wheel for pendulum (pyproject.toml): started
#0 94.04   Building wheel for pendulum (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#0 94.04   Created wheel for pendulum: filename=pendulum-2.1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.whl size=109769 sha256=2373b525a3ca7c5991eb07b0fb7fd31663a114e998480b9d4e09fe658f154152
#0 94.04   Stored in directory: /home/etl/.cache/pip/wheels/c7/33/5b/9bd231ee982125a3e4eaa5c77a04de43eba25ee940cfb5a84a
#0 94.04 Successfully built pendulum
#0 94.04 Failed to build psutil
#0 94.04 ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install --user etl --upgrade pip     && pip3 install --user etl -r /tmp/python_requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

[image]

I know I can fix this problem in MacOS by installing *python-devel* in centos7, but I want to understand why the images behave differently.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code that generated those two PNG files?  Or if it's supposed to be the output of `docker build` on the different platforms, can you replace them with the actual text output of that command?  (You should almost never include a screen shot of a terminal window in a question; it will be much easier to read, search for, and reproduce plain text.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The command that generates the two images was a simple docker build . (as shown in the first image). It was the exact same command in both cases.

Comment: other solution: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/pull/2103 ?

Answer (score 4):

The suggested answer by freddy worked for me. I added `--platform linux/amd64` to my build command. I plan to add it to all my future docker commands on my m1 arm, though I admit I don't know which commands need it or not.

Example commands I ran:

```
docker push --platform linux/amd64 brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm
docker pull --platform linux/amd64 brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -f ~/iit-term-synthesis/Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/
docker run -v /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis:/home/bot/iit-term-synthesis \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq:/home/bot/pycoq \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils:/home/bot/ultimate-utils \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001:/home/bot/proverbot9001 \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/data:/home/bot/data \
           --platform linux/amd64 \
           -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test bash
```

see for details: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-problems-mac/

Answer (score 3):

After a long search, I found this article https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-problems-mac/

The problem was the chip architecture (arm). The solutions proposed in the article above are working (either building from the source, getting precompiled binaries, or adding `--platform linux/amd64` when building with Docker)

Comment: you should write some sample docker commands as examples.